# Job message shown in inbox, but I can't access it Page not found

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

A few days ago I got a reply from an employer that I sent a job application to. Now I can't access the message/application anymore. I can see it in my inbox at the top, but when clicking on it it says "Oh no! We can't find the page you're looking for." This is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages/4901698

Since it's a job I'm really interested in, I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you logged into the same account that received the message?

Comment: @ivami Yes. But the thing is that I recently changed the email address associated with the account. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Looks like you've had a recent account merge, @KhoaTran: I'll put this in front of someone who can fix it for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

This issue should now be resolved. We found a bug in the merge process that wasn't properly reassociating messages Jobs.